# Is it possible to re-use once created Eclipse Maven repository index in a new workspace?

Tags: eclipse, maven

When there is a need to create a new workspace in Eclipse it seems to involve rebuilding Maven global repository index which is a slow process and I guess it also takes some extra space on disk per workspace.

Is it really needed or is there an option to have some common index that all workspaces can use?

Or can I copy/link some directory straight to my new workspace so that no another indexing would be needed?

*It would be great if `m2e` plugin had an option for this. Now it assumes every workspace uses its own cache.*

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

My current hacky solution using Linux is to share the folder (now that I found it) that contains cached index. In Eclipse the workspace folder there should be folder:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/nexus
```

When I have managed to update Maven repositories for the first workspace I have created then whenever I create a new one I just delete that `nexus` folder in the new workspace and link the already updated folder there, so something like:

```
cd NEW_WS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core
rm -r nexus
ln -s FIRST_WS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/nexus
```